# Set the Date / Time locale to de_AT instead of de_DE on Microsoft Azure Website (PHP)

Tags: php, azure

I am currently developing a a Website that will be hosted on Microsoft Azure Websites. The client (as well as I) live in Austria and thus we would like to have the Austrian (German) locale for time and date - there is a small difference in the dates as we say "Jänner" instead of "Januar" for "January" and "Januar" sounds somewhat strange to an austrian. The standard snippet for returning a german date would be like so:

```
function ger_date($date){
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Vienna"); 
    setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8','de_DE', 'de_DE@euro', 'german');   
    $longdate = strftime('%d. %B %Y', strtotime($date));
    return $longdate;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is acutlly fairly simple. To have austrian or swiss date formats, you can change the locales to the corresponding languages.

```
function ger_date($date){
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Vienna"); 
    setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_AT.utf8','de_AT', 'de_AT@euro', 'german_austria');   
    $longdate = strftime('%d. %B %Y', strtotime($date));
    return $longdate;

}
```

for austrian
or

```
function ger_date($date){
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Vienna"); 
    setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_CH.utf8','de_CH', 'de_CH@euro', 'german_switzerland');   
    $longdate = strftime('%d. %B %Y', strtotime($date));
    return $longdate;
}
```

for swiss german. (note that there is not much difference in the regional format between german and switzerland)

But please note, that german_austria outputs Jänner, which sometimes can render as J�nner as the last locale ('german_austria', 'german'  or 'german_switzerland') is not an UTF8 Locale and 'german-austria.utf8' is not available on my host.

If your system has no UTF-8 compatible locale installed and you can not install a nother one, you can simply wrap the strftime function into the utf8_encode() function from PHP and everything should work like a charm.